# Different web service calls for different view controllers Restkit

Tags: ios, web-services, ipad, restkit

I'm an asp.net developer and starting to learn objective c. Been struggling for days to find a fix for this:

I'm completely new to ios development so forgive me if my question sound stupid.

I have 2 table view controllers:

AnnouncementsTableViewController and NewsTableViewController.

For each of these controllers Im calling a web service using rest kit:
Here's my code in NewsTableViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self sendRequest];

}
- (void)sendRequest
{

//set the base URL
RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:@"http://someurl.com/WcfDataService.svc"];
NSString *format=@"json";
NSString *un = @"blah";
NSString *pw = @"blah";

RKObjectManager *objectManager1 = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
objectManager1.client.baseURL = baseURL;


NSDictionary *queryParams;
queryParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:format,@"format", nil];

objectManager1.client.username=un;
objectManager1.client.password=pw;

//set news mapping

RKObjectMapping *newsMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[News class]];


[newsMapping setSetDefaultValueForMissingAttributes:true]; 
[newsMapping mapKeyPath:@"NEWSTITLE" 
            toAttribute:@"name"]; 

[newsMapping mapKeyPath:@"NEWSBODY" 
            toAttribute:@"newsBody"]; 


 RKURL *newsURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURL:[objectManager1 baseURL] resourcePath:@"/NEWS"   queryParameters:queryParams];


 [objectManager1 loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?$%@", [newsURL resourcePath], [newsURL query]] usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) 

 {

     [loader.mappingProvider setObjectMapping:newsMapping forKeyPath:@"d"];

     loader.method = RKRequestMethodGET;

     loader.delegate = self;

     loader.userData=@"NewsData";
 }];

}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)request:(RKRequest*)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse*)response {
NSLog(@"response code: %d", [response statusCode]);
}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects
{
NSString* source = (NSString*) objectLoader.userData;

NSLog(@"objects[%d]", [objects count]);
NSLog(@"%@", source);
data2 = objects;


 [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

And I'm doing the exact same code as above on AnnouncementsViewController (just changing the base URL and mappings).

Problem is it only loads for the newstableviewcontroller and not on announcements.

I have read this https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Using-Multiple-Base-URLs-%28and-Multiple-Object-Managers%29

but cant seem to understand and apply on my code.

I hope someone can shed some light!

Best regards,
Rikuna

Comment: Turn on logging and see what it tells you: RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);

Comment: @PauldeLange Thanks for the comment. added the RKLogLevelTrace and RKLogConfigureByName. For the newstablecontroller, it returns data from the web service, but for announcementstablecontroller, it returns nothing. They are both returning data just not both at the same time. What am i missing?

Comment: Is the outgoing URL correct? Can you put that URL into a REST client and get data back?

Comment: @PauldeLange if i comment out codes on the 1st tableviewcontroller, 2ndViewcontroller works fine. and vice versa. Which means there's no problem with the outgoing URL.

Comment: You are going to have to post the RESTkit logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PauldeLange thanks for taking time to respond. I've finally fixed it. This line is just what did the magic:

```
 RKObjectManager *objectManager =  [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
```